# How do I make a blanket statement to be notified if certain wallets mint?

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, web3.py, contract-debugging, python

I've been trying to come up with a way to track wallets and be notified when they 'mint'. The way i'm doing it now seems like it will only catch around 50% of all transactions due to the nature of the code. I'm checking the transactions to see if they include;

```
    "mint(address,uint256)",
    "mint(uint256)",
    "mint(address)",
    "mint()",
    "mint(uint32,bytes32[],uint64,bytes)",
    "mint(bytes32[])",
    "whitelistMint(uint256,bytes32[])",
    "mintAllowList(address,address,address,uint256,MintParams,bytes32[])"
]
```

but I feel like some contracts will have their own version of the mint function and this will miss them. Is there a blanket statement I can do to try and future proof this code to capture ALL minting functions?

-- I am using my own personal node to grab the transaction to avoid API limits.

Comment: Could using a regex possible work? Open to all suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor the contracts `Transfer` event, it is only emitted when an NFT is transferred ( and minted ) like in the code below, dont forget to replace the part of the code that require the actual contract addresses and wallet addresses you want to track, also this code is not future-proof because new standards or custom implementations might not emit the `Transfer` event.

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

const ERC721_ABI = [
  "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed tokenId)"
];

const ERC1155_ABI = [
  "event TransferSingle(address indexed operator, address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 id, uint256 value)"
];

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(YOUR_RPC_URL);

const erc721ContractAddress = '0x123...';
const erc1155ContractAddress = '0x456...';

const erc721Contract = new ethers.Contract(erc721ContractAddress, ERC721_ABI, provider);
const erc1155Contract = new ethers.Contract(erc1155ContractAddress, ERC1155_ABI, provider);

const trackedWallets = new Set(['0xabc...', '0xdef...']);

function handleTransfer(from, to, tokenId) {
  if (trackedWallets.has(to)) {
    console.log(`Detected mint to wallet ${to} with tokenId ${tokenId}`);
  }
}

erc721Contract.on('Transfer', handleTransfer);
erc1155Contract.on('TransferSingle', handleTransfer);
```